# Which of these SQL UPDATE statements would be faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Which would be faster?

**Method A:**

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.column1 = table2.column1 
FROM table2
WHERE table1.column2 = table2.column2
```

**Method B:**

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.column1 = table2.column1 
FROM table1
JOIN table2 on table1.column2 = table2.column2
```

Will they generate the same execution plan?

Is there any case where I should avoid one of them?

Some tests I did took them almost the same time to execute, but always good to hear a second opnion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are equivalent. You can verify this by checking the execution plan yourself. The second option:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.column1 = table2.column1
FROM table1 JOIN
     table2 on table1.column2 = table2.column2
```

Is currently the preferred method for writing queries, as it's more clear why the criteria is being specified.

Comment: "Is currently the preferred method" -- preferred by whom? Not I ;)

Comment: Yes. Oldies like me still prefer the old ways, but now I guess we have to be able to read and write both.

Comment: Kinda getting off-topic I guess, but a comma-separated list of tables produces a Cartesian product until you bother to "join" them in the `WHERE` clause. The separation of join criteria and filter criteria is *arguably* easier to read. `JOIN` syntax also forces you to specify conditions so you can't forget and end up with unexpected results. Still - both are valid and I do see younger developers sometimes putting the "older" method into new code.

Comment: Oh, by the way, do you know if there is any difference of algorythms used to process one or another depending on the amount of data or other variables? I mean, both would perform the same if I have 100 records tables or 1000000 records tables? One guy pointed that it might happen and in that case adding conditions to the where clause would be better. Never heard that so would be nice to check that as well. Thanks for the help, always instructive!